# I am getting an error in pgadmin as "unrecognized configuration parameter "lc_collate" " how to fix this?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, pgadmin-4, postgresql-16

[Refer this!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrjdB.jpg)

I was creating a database and got this error i tried to uninstall and then reinstall postgresql-16 and pgadmin4 but it didn't work for me! It creates a database but gives this error i am worried that what if it would block my task when i am half done !

Comment: 1) Do not use images, copy and paste text into your question. 2) Look at the Postgres log and see what command is hitting the database and what the complete error message is.

Answer (score 3):

The parameter `lc_collate` got removed in PostgreSQL v16, because it didn't reflect the actual collation any more.

Use a version of pgAdmin that supports PostgreSQL v16. According to the [release notes](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/8.3/release_notes.html), that should be 7.8 or better (but use the latest one).

Comment: Are you sure about that? [CREATE DATABASE PG 16](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-createdatabase.html) `select version(); PostgreSQL 16.2` then `create database collate_test lc_collate 'en_US.UTF-8'; CREATE DATABASE`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver What about `CREATE DATABASE xy LOCALE_PROVIDER icu ICU_LOCALE 'de-AT' LOCALE 'C' TEMPLATE template0`? If you ran `SHOW lc_collate`, and the result is `C`, is that meaningful?

Comment: The question was about creating a database and getting a lc_collate error. You can `CREATE DATABASE` with `lc_collate` in PG 16 without an error. The issue  is you cannot do `SHOW lc_collate;` as it returns the error the OP is seeing `ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "lc_collate"`. So it would seem the version of pgAdmin is issuing a `SHOW lc_collate;` somewhere in the process.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver My comment tried to explain to you _why_ the parameter was removed, even though you have `lc_collate` in `CREATE DATABASE`. Sure, pgAdmin should not look for that parameter, which is why my answer recommends to upgrade to a version of pgAdmin that understands about PostgreSQL v16.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have an older verison of SQL installed, and delete it.
This fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Update to `the latest version of` **`pgAdmin 4`** to resolve this issue.

The version disparity between **`PostgreSQL`** and **`pgAdmin 4`** caused this problem and other issues such as the inability to **Backup** the database.

Answer (score 0):

Re: "The parameter lc_collate got removed in PostgreSQL v16, because it didn't reflect the actual collation any more."

Clarification - the text of the PostgreSQL 16 Doc post speaks to only the "server" level variables having been removed, not the database level.

"Remove read-only server variables lc_collate and lc_ctype (Peter Eisentraut)"

Comment: It appears [to me] that your "answer" is actually a comment to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77975676/i-am-getting-an-error-in-pgadmin-as-unrecognized-configuration-parameter-lc-co/77979710#77979710). If so, then you should not post comments as answers simply because you do not yet have enough reputation points to post comments. If you feel that it is an answer (and not a comment) then I suggest that you [edit] your answer and add a link to the "documentation" that you are referring to. By the way (and pardon my ignorance), who is _Peter Eisentraut_ ?